# Option input is not updating to WordPress database, when I update the input it just copy's the value of another input

Tags: php, wordpress

Here are a few functions that I am using:

```
function dp_find_results($table_name) {
   global $wpdb;

    $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "
        SELECT * 
        FROM  $table_name
        WHERE role = 'member' OR role = 'admin'
    " );

    echo '<table><form action="" method="POST">';
    foreach ( $result as $page )
    {
        if($page->role === 'member') {
            $value1 = 'admin';
            $value2 = 'Super Admin';
        } elseif($page->role ==='admin') {
            $value1 = 'member';
            $value2 = 'Super Admin';
        } else {
            $value1 = 'member';
            $value2 = 'admin';
        }

        echo
            '<tr>
                <th>Role</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Update</th>
            </tr>';

        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>
                <select name="role">
                  <option value="' . $page->role . '">' . $page->role . '</option>
                  <option value="' . $value1 . '">' . $value1 . '</option>
                  <option value="' . $value2 . '">' . $value2 . '</option>
                </select>
                </td>';
            echo '<td>' . $page->username .'</td>';
            echo '<td><button class="danzerpress-button-modern" type="submit" name="role-update-' . $page->username . '" value="' . $page->username . '">Update</button></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</form></table>';

}

function get_registered_users() {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = 'dp_user_roles';

    $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "
        SELECT * 
        FROM  $table_name
    " );

    $users = array();
        foreach ($result as $arrayResult) {
            array_push($users, 'role-update-' . $arrayResult->username);

        }
    //returns role-update-$username
    return $users;

}

//checking for each registered user to match the button being posted
$variables = get_registered_users();

foreach($variables as $variable_name){

    if(isset($_POST[$variable_name])){

        $role = $_POST['role'];
        $username = $_POST[$variable_name];

        echo $role . '<br>' . $username . '<br>';
        //after confirming submission is correct, update table
        dp_change_user_role($role, $username);

    }

}
function dp_change_user_role($role, $username) {
        $table_name = 'dp_user_roles';
        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->update( $table_name, 
            array( 
                'role' => $role
            ),
                array(
                    'username' => $username )   
        );
    }
```

Here it is in action
https://gyazo.com/62c0bdaca6a4c1443d011b8830d41130, the weird thing I am experiencing is that the bottom table row updates but the first table row will only change to the value the bottom table row is. I've tried a few things for trouble shooting but can't get my head around why it's not working. If I remove one of them then the changes work fine with no issues.

Here is another gif of the problem, here is what happens if I update the bottom one and then update the top one: https://gyazo.com/85956608dabe973ea8907b19daeb0094 very weird interaction and I can't figure out why it's doing it. This is the main issue unless you find others :).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring out what is was, $_POST['role'], was grabbing values from the other options and was not a unique identifier. So all the forms had options with the name="role". So added something unique so it would post correctly.

```
//checking for each registered user to match the button being posted
$variables = get_registered_users();

foreach($variables as $variable_name){

    if(isset($_POST[$variable_name])){
        //$role = $POST['role'] is wrong and needs to change
        $role = $_POST['role'];
        $username = $_POST[$variable_name];

        echo $role . '<br>' . $username . '<br>';
        //after confirming submission is correct, update table
        dp_change_user_role($role, $username);

    }

}
             //This is where the role would need to change name="" to something that will identify it as unique
             <select name="role">
                  <option value="' . $page->role . '">' . $page->role . '</option>
                  <option value="' . $value1 . '">' . $value1 . '</option>
                  <option value="' . $value2 . '">' . $value2 . '</option>
                </select>
```